# random_shuffle not really random

Tags: c++, random, srand

I'm using the `random_shuffle` on a vector like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
vector <Card> deck;
//some code to add cards to the deck here
random_shuffle ( deck.begin(), deck.end() );
```

When run, the content of the deck is mixed up, but this mixed-up order is kept when I restart the program.

Did I miss something? How can I make it truly random?

Comment: You for got to seed rand `srand`.

Comment: `std :: srand(std :: time(NULL))`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to seed the psuedo-random number generator first using [srand](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

...

std::srand(std::time(0));

vector <Card> deck;
//some code to add cards to the deck here
random_shuffle ( deck.begin(), deck.end() );
```

Note from link above:

> Generally speaking, the pseudo-random number generator should only be
>   seeded once, before any calls to rand(), and the start of the program.
>   It should not be repeatedly seeded, or reseeded every time you wish to
>   generate a new batch of pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: @Chin: note that you should seed the generator once when the program starts and never again.

Comment: is there any difference between time(0) and time(NULL)?

Comment: Good point I assumed the code he posted was part of `int main()`. I included the excerpt from the link..

Comment: @Chin, `NULL` should be used with pointers, and has been superseded by `nullptr`.

Comment: @Chin There are three ways of writing a null pointer in C++: Using the old `NULL` (inherited from C), using `0` (the old C++ way) and using the new C++11 keyword `nullptr`.

Comment: I think `cstdlib` is not needed, but `ctime` instead, otherwise I get a "identifier `time` is undefined"

Comment: `srand()` requires `cstdlib`. Something else might be pulling it in for you, but you should included it anyway.

Comment: `random_shuffle()` isn't actually specified to use `rand()` and so `srand()` may not have any impact. If you want to be sure, you should use one of the C++11 forms, `random_shuffle(b, e, RNG)` or `shuffle(b, e, uRNG)`

Comment: That is correct, it just so happens that `rand` is often used.

Comment: You have to `#include <ctime>` for `std::time()`.

Answer (score 10):

With current C++ (i.e. C++11) you can use the `shuffle` algorithm which can take a pseudo random number generator (PRNG) object (which you can seed) as third parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  vector<string> v;
  for (int i = 1; i<argc; ++i)
    v.push_back(argv[i]);
  mt19937 g(static_cast<uint32_t>(time(0)));
  shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
  for (auto &x : v)
    cout << x << ' ';
  cout << '\n';
}
```

(for GCC 4.8.2 you need to compile it via `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g shuffle.cc -o shuffle`)

In the above example, the PRNG is seeded with the current system time.

For pre-C++11 compilers you only have the `random_shuffle` algorithm in the STL - but even with that you can optionally specify a number generator object/function to it. Note that you can't just pluck in a PRNG object like `mtl19937` into it (because it does not provide a `operator()(U upper_bound)` member).

Thus, you can supply your own adapter like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

struct Gen {
  mt19937 g;
  Gen()
   : g(static_cast<uint32_t>(time(0)))
  {
  }
  size_t operator()(size_t n)
  {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> d(0, n ? n-1 : 0);
    return d(g);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  vector<string> v;
  for (int i = 1; i<argc; ++i)
    v.push_back(argv[i]);
  random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), Gen());
  for (vector<string>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
    cout << *i << ' ';
  cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Place the line:

```
srand (time (0));
```

in your code before you do *anything* else, such as at the start of `main()`.

Without that, the default seed of 1 will always be used, leading to identical sequences from `rand()` and anything that uses it.