# Sampling Data into two Groups

Tags: c++, random, stl, stl-algorithm, subsampling

I am seeking help to make the code below efficient. I not satisfied though it works. There is bug to be fixed (currently irrelevant). I am using < random> header for the first time and stable_partition for first time.

The Problem definition/specification:
I have a population (vector) of numerical data (float values). I want to create two RANDOM samples (2 vectors) based on a user specified percentage. i.e. popu_data = 30%Sample1 + 70%Sample2 - here 30% will be given by the user. I didnt implement as % yet but its trivial.

The Problem in Programming: I am able to create the 30% Sample from the population. The 2nd part of creating another vector (sample2 - 70%) is my problem. The reason being while selecting the 30% data, I have to select the values randomly. I have to keep track of the indexes to remove them. But some how I am not getting an efficient logic than the one I implemented.

My Logic is (NOT happy): In the population data, the values at random indexes are replaced with a unique value (here it is 0.5555). Later I learnt about stable_partition function where individual values of the Population are compared with 0.5555. On false, that data is created as a new Sample2 which complements sample1.

Further to this: How can I make this Generic i.e. a population into N sub-samples of user defined % of population.

Thank you for any help. I tried vector erase, remove, copy etc but it didn't materialize as the current code. I am looking for a better and more efficient logic and stl usage.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool Is05555 (float i){
    if ( i > 0.5560 ) return true;
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_real_distribution<> dis(1, 2);
    vector<float>randVals;

    cout<<"All the Random Values between 1 and 2"<<endl;
    for (int n = 0; n < 20; ++n) {
        float rnv = dis(gen);
        cout<<rnv<<endl;
        randVals.push_back(rnv);
    }
    cout << '\n';

    random_device rd2;
    mt19937 gen2(rd2());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,19);

    vector<float>sample;
    vector<float>sample2;
    for (int n = 0; n < 6; ++n) {
        float rnv = dist(gen2);
        sample.push_back(randVals.at(rnv));
        randVals.at(rnv) = 0.5555;
    }

    cout<<"Random Values between 1 and 2 with 0.5555 a Unique VAlue"<<endl;
    for (int n = 0; n < 20; ++n) {
        cout<<randVals.at(n)<<" ";
    }
    cout << '\n';

    std::vector<float>::iterator bound;
    bound = std::stable_partition (randVals.begin(), randVals.end(), Is05555);

    for (std::vector<float>::iterator it=randVals.begin(); it!=bound; ++it)
        sample2.push_back(*it);

    cout<<sample.size()<<","<<sample2.size()<<endl;

    cout<<"Random Values between 1 and 2 Subset of 6 only: "<<endl;

    for (int n = 0; n < sample.size(); ++n) {
        cout<<sample.at(n)<<" ";
    }
    cout << '\n';

    cout<<"Random Values between 1 and 2 - Remaining: "<<endl;
    for (int n = 0; n < sample2.size(); ++n) {
        cout<<sample2.at(n)<<" ";
    }
    cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: algorithm function set_difference probably will rescue me - just saw that function popping up on right side column. However, it seems I have to sort before using which is not convincing.

Comment: For your 30% sample, do you need each sample chosen with 30% probability (could result in sample size *slightly* different from 30%) or exactly 30% of the items chosen? Do you need your results in the original order, or is order of the sample irrelevant?

Comment: `vector<float>sample;
    for (int n = 0; n < 6; ++n) {
 float rnv = dist(gen2);
 sample.push_back(randVals.at(rnv));
    }

    sort(randVals.begin(), randVals.end());
    sort(sample.begin(), sample.end());

    vector <float> sample2;
    set_difference(randVals.begin(), randVals.end(),       sample.begin(), sample.end(),inserter(sample2,sample2.end()));`   **the code using set_difference - it works**

Comment: @JerryCoffin - for my current needs, probability is irrelevant. that complexity is avoided for now. 30% just means 30% of the data/values from the population. I thought about the order - order of sample is irrelevant. I am facing another problem: In my code, the line (n<6), the random indexes selected are repeating, how do I control repetition of indexes i.e have unique indexes only (the bug I was mentioning above)????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a requirement for an N% sample, with order irrelevant, it's probably easiest to just do something like:

```
std::random_shuffle(randVals.begin(), randVals.end());
int num = randVals.size() * percent / 100.0;

auto pos = randVals.begin() + randVals.size() - num;

// get our sample
auto sample1{pos, randVals.end()};

// remove sample from original collection
randVals.erase(pos, randVals.end());
```

For some types of items in the array, you could improve this by moving items from the original array to the sample array, but for simple types like `float` or `double`, that won't accomplish anything.

Comment: Thank you. Looking for crisp and efficient code. Either we pick randomly (the one I implemented - long & dirty) or random shuffle and get a contiguous piece from the pie (crisp and efficient) - thank you.

Comment: As per this posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459953/random-shuffle-not-really-random?rq=1, I think I should use srand function above the 5 lines you mentioned ???? Thank you. !! std::srand(std::time(0));