# std::random_shuffle produce the same result even though srand(time(0)) called once

Tags: c++, random, vector, srand

In a function, I want to generate a list of numbers in range:
(This function will be called only once when executing the program.)

```
void DataSet::finalize(double trainPercent, bool genValidData)
{
    srand(time(0));
    printf("%d\n", rand());

    // indices = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., m_train.size()-1}
    vector<size_t> indices(m_train.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < indices.size(); i++)
        indices[i] = i;

    random_shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end());
// Output
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%ld ", indices[i]);
    puts("");

}
```

The results are like:

```
850577673
246 239 7 102 41 201 288 23 1 237
```

After a few seconds:

```
856981140
246 239 7 102 41 201 288 23 1 237
```

And more:

```
857552578
246 239 7 102 41 201 288 23 1 237
```

Why the function `rand()` works properly but `random_shuffle' does not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make sure that std::random\_shuffle always produces a different result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931951/how-to-make-sure-that-stdrandom-shuffle-always-produces-a-different-result)

Comment: You should only call `srand()` once, at the beginning of your program. Also, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926433/how-to-shuffle-a-stdvector-in-c), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459953/random-shuffle-not-really-random)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, not a duplicate because he called `srand` once. Right?

Comment: @PaulDraper Once *every time* he ran it. Also, there's lots of other advice on that question and the others I've linked. I can only mark one duplicate.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks. I've read the advice. But I cannot figure out why `rand()` works and `random_shuffle()` doesn't seem to have any associations with `srand()`.

Comment: I move `srand()` call into `main` function, but the results are similar.

Comment: Can you see the example in here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/

I tried it and it gives me a different vector each time. And it uses `srand()`.

Comment: @yasouser Yes, it works. The lambda-expr version: `random_shuffle(begin(indices), end(indices), [](int n) { return rand() % n; });` produces different result, but if I change my random generator to default_random_engine(), then the problems come. So the question becomes that why `default_random_engine()` not works.

Comment: @YangDawei: I modified the sample I cited to print the vector after the call to random_shuffle() with built-in random number generator. It also prints different vector each time. I'm using MinGW g++ v4.8.1 to compile the code on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`random_shuffle()` isn't actually specified to use `rand()` and so `srand()` may not have any impact. If you want to be sure, you should use one of the C++11 forms, `random_shuffle(b, e, RNG)` or `shuffle(b, e, uRNG)`.

An alternative would be to use `random_shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end(), rand());` because apparently your implementation of `random_shuffle()` is not using `rand()`.

Comment: Yes, I force the random_shuffle to use `rand()` so that it works properly. Instead of `random_shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end(), rand())`, I use `random_shuffle(begin(indices), end(indices), [](int n) { return rand() % n; })` because the previous one produce errors. I use cmake installed by macports, with CXX flags -std=c++11. My g++ is clang-500.2.79, but I don't know what compiler is used exactly by cmake.

Comment: @YangDawei: you can, for example, `message("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")` in your `CMakeLists.txt` to find out which compiler is used.