# random_shuffle and srand() give me the same result every time

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation

I'm trying to produce do some processing on a random permutation of the alphabet, however each permutation produces the same result despite using srand(myseed)
I have included the `<algorithm>` header.

```
string create_permutation(unsigned seed)
{
    srand(seed);
    string permutation = ALPHABET;
    random_shuffle(permutation.begin(), permutation.end());
    return permutation;
}

cout << create_permutation(2) << endl; // or 3, 4, 5 etc
// continuously returns 'XQACKHSLOJ,TRBZNGV.W FIUEYDMP
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

*EDIT 2:* adjustment to mcve

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>   

using namespace std;

const string ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,' ";
string create_permutation(unsigned seed)
{
    srand(seed);
    string permutation = ALPHABET;
    random_shuffle(permutation.begin(), permutation.end());
    return permutation;
}

int main(){    
    cout << create_permutation(2) << endl; // or 3, 4, 5 etc
    // continuously returns 'XQACKHSLOJ,TRBZNGV.W FIUEYDMP
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108780/why-do-i-always-get-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers-with-rand

Comment: I did browse the issue before posting, with each post holding any similarity to mine the solution has always been to use _srand(seed)_ which I have already done.

Comment: Related: stop using `random_shuffle` and start using [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle). The former is deprecated and will be dropped eventually. See the last sample in the link provided for an example of how to do this.

Comment: What is your seed and where did you get it from?

Comment: Added an mvce. Hope that helps.

Comment: You complete example is not very complete.  You can't run it.

Comment: Are you passing the same seed every time?

Comment: If you are using the same seed every time: Go read the docs. Otherwise, [cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0271e625ab0b8c3a).

Comment: @NathanOliver It does not have to be runnable, it needs to be complete yet minimum. Unless there is a reason that this program ***must*** be ran,  then what the author has provided is fine. Also, you should always ask the author to provide the needed details and give them time to provide these details. After they fail to do so, then you should flag the question and suggest others to do so as well.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I'm so sad to see that even our long time members who have earned so much reputation are so quick to judge a question. 1) If you think this situation is not reproducible, you should first ask the author to provide more details that could possibly reproduce the outcome. 2) Only after giving the author a respectable amount of time to provide a few quick details, should you flag the post as "cannot reproduce". 3) This post is reproducible! You just didn't do the research to see what was need to produce the results. Using his platform and compiler, you will get the same results.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt Hey the Meta Police is here! 1)  I already gave him the link to the MCVE help page which tells him to *"Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included"*. 2) So far, no one has voted to close this, so I don't get your point. 3) *"This post is reproducible!"* Not with the information he provides. *"Using his platform and compiler, you will get the same results."* I cannot do that without knowing which platform that is.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt, if you change the parameters so you don't resuse the same seed, the problem is not reproducible. The primary bug hinges on the reuse of the same seed.

Comment: @NickLewers, change the parameter for `create_permutation` to take in `unsigned int seed` not `unsigned seed`.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt That's the exact same thing.

Comment: @BaummitAugen _"I cannot do that without knowing which platform that is."_ Of course not, that is why you should ***ask*** for that information.

Comment: @user4581301 The author has in a comment that passing any of the numbers, `2, 3, 4, or 5, etc` will result in the same outcome. The same seed is not always used.

Comment: In that case, back to Baum mit Augen's statement of non reproducible. I can't reproduce either.

Answer (score 7):

#### The problem

- The shuffles aren't random because `shuffle_random` is using the same seed for the random number generator each time it is called.

`srand` does not seed the `random_shuffle` function, it seeds `rand` and `random_shuffle` **usually** calls `rand`, but **does not have to**.

`random_shuffle` has two forms:

- One that takes 2 arguments (begin/end iterators)
- One that takes 3 (begin/end iterator and a random generator).

You have demonstrated that you know how to use the first form, but the problem with the first form is that it is implemented differently on different platforms and with different compilers. It may not use `rand()` at all, which is the function that `srand` seeds.

You should use the 3 argument form and provide the random number generator as a parameter to the function.

You can follow [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21598352/2542856) to learn how to make your own random number generator, or you can provide `rand()` to the `random_shuffle` function as the random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you seed the random number generator, you set the starting point for an algorithm that will provide a sequence of psuedorandom numbers. If you always use the same seed, the algorithm will always have the same starting point and always generate the same sequence of numbers.
2. Every time you call `srand`, you reset the seed and reset the starting point for the algorithm.

   1. A common bug here is to repeatedly call `srand`. Unless you have a very good reason not to (and if you do, you probably shouldn't use `rand` and srand at all. [Look to the `<random>` library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random)) you should call `srand` once at the beginning of the program to seed the generator once and ever after use that seed.
   2. `srand` is also quite expensive. From a performance standpoint, you don't want to call it often.

So: since every call to `create_permutation` calls `srand` with the `seed` parameter and `create_permutation` is always called with the same seed value, for a given implementation of the random number generator, `create_permutation` will always use the same random number sequence and thus generate the same permutation.

A quick example that will generate different permutations, so long as the program is not run more often than once per second is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

const std::string ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,' ";
std::string create_permutation()
{
    std::string permutation = ALPHABET;
    std::random_shuffle(permutation.begin(), permutation.end());
    return permutation;
}

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL)); // caveat: time's minimum resolution is 1 second.
                       // multiple executions of this program within 1
                       // second will get the same time and use the same seed.
    std::cout << create_permutation() << std::endl;
    std::cout << create_permutation() << std::endl;
    std::cout << create_permutation() << std::endl;
    std::cout << create_permutation() << std::endl;
    std::cout << create_permutation() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

A more modern approach:

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

const std::string ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,' ";
std::random_device rd; // Warning: implementation of this is allowed to be stupid and 
                       // return the same value every time. Does not work in mingw 4.8
                       // Can't speak for 4.9 or greater
std::mt19937 randomizer(rd());


std::string create_permutation()
{
    std::string permutation = ALPHABET;
    std::shuffle(permutation.begin(), permutation.end(), randomizer);
    return permutation;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << create_permutation() << std::endl;
    std::cout << create_permutation() << std::endl;
    std::cout << create_permutation() << std::endl;
    std::cout << create_permutation() << std::endl;
    std::cout << create_permutation() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The first example you give is the same as the author's code, is it not?

Comment: Yes. Odd. Not sure what happened there. Wrong stuff in the paste buffer, I guess.